# (Python 2.7) Get UI title bar size

Tags: python, python-2.7, titlebar, win32gui

**Premise**

I launch a `some program.exe` using arguments `-width 640 -height 480` which cause the program to launch in the specified size.

Then I want to *verify* if the progam launched in the specified size so using `win32gui.GetWindowRect()` I calculated the window size:

```
>>> r = win32gui.GetWindowRect(HWND)
>>> w = r[2] - r[0]
>>> h = r[3] - r[1]
>>> print w,h
646 509
```

The size does not match. I presume that it's most likely due to the **title bar**.

My question is: *How to get the size of the title bar?*

**Note:** I need to know the size of the title bar in order to **verify** the program size, therefore using `win32gui.GetWindowRect()` and subtract its value with the expected size is not a solution.

**Image to clarify my problem**

[image: Image to clarify what I am searching for (image has been modified to hide the program and a few pieces of information)]

**Additional question**

Does different Operating System have different size of the **title bar** and **border**?

According to *my own calculation* (information not officially confirmed) at default Windows 10, the size of the border is `3px` and the height of the title bar is `26px`. Can someone confirm/rebuke this information?

Answer (score 4):

Option 1:
You can hard code and give it fixed offset of 8px from the left right and bottom, and 31px from top to remove the invisible borders and title bar from the top.

but this way when you change the windows scale, it will no longer work properly, this option is great if you are coding to use the program yourself. If you want the program be compatible with multiple scales, try Option 2.

Option 2:

You can use `GetClientRect` to get the size of window without the title bar and the invisible borders, then you can use it to calculate the offset

```
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    clientRect = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
    windowOffset = math.floor(((rect[2]-rect[0])-clientRect[2])/2)
    titleOffset = ((rect[3]-rect[1])-clientRect[3]) - windowOffset
    newRect = (rect[0]+windowOffset, rect[1]+titleOffset, rect[2]-windowOffset, rect[3]-windowOffset)
```

here newRect is the rect without the title bar or the invisible borders

Source:
[GetWindowRect](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32gui__GetWindowRect_meth.html)
[GetClientRect](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32gui__GetClientRect_meth.html)